# How to reset the thead default styles?

Tags: css

Previuosly there is no thead tag before tr.
Now,for tablesorter functionality i added thead tag due to that header styles are differing because of default thead styles conflicting.I should reset the thead styles while loading of the window.please tell me how to reset the thead styles and should work table grid color as per previous exisiting css.

```
               <thead id="Header">
                <tr class="header">                       
                <th class="th-border" id="name">Name</th>
               </tr>
              </thead>
```

Thanks,

EDIT:
Previuosly no thead tag,whenever added the thead tag in my page table design is chnaging.I don't want to change the table style.please tell me how to reset the default thead styles?

Comment: What “default thead styles” are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

just prepend your style selector with thead

like

```
thead tr th{
 color:blue;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```